# Python pandas - headers on two lines

Tags: python, pandas

Using the pandas library for python I am reading a csv, then grouping the results with a sum.

```
grouped = df[['Organization Name','Views']].groupby('Organization Name').sum().sort(columns='Views',ascending=False).head(10)
#Bar Chart Section
print grouped.to_string()
```

Unfortunately I get the following result for the table:

```
                                      Views
Organization Name
Test1                                 112
Test2                                 114
Test3                                 115
```

it seems that the column headers are going on two separate rows.

Comment: If yoiu're referring to 'Organization Name', this is the name of your index, you can set this to `None`, `grouped.index.name = None`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you grouped on 'Organization Name', this is being used as the name for your index, you can set this to `None` using:

```
grouped.index.name = None
```

Will then remove the line, this is just a display issue, your data is not in some funny shape

Alternatively if you don't want 'Organization Name' to become the index then pass `as_index=False` to `groupby`:

```
grouped = df[['Organization Name','Views']].groupby('Organization Name', as_index=False).sum().sort(columns='Views',ascending=False).head(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

`grouped.reset_index()` should fix this. This happened because you have grouped the data and aggregated on a column.